# Laravel (mime?) video extension validation

Tags: forms, file-upload, laravel, mime-types, validation

I'm creating a video uploader but I can't seem to get the validation right.

Right now what I've got is:

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'form-submit','files'=>true)) }}
{{ Form::file('videos[]', ['multiple' => true]) }}
{{ Form::submit('Upload video') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::any('form-submit', function(){
$files = Input::file('videos');

foreach($files as $file) {
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required|mimes:video/x-flv,video/mp4,video/mp2t,video/3gpp,video/quicktime,video/x-msvideo,video/x-ms-wmv|max:200000'
    );
    $validator = \Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
    if($validator->passes()){

        $id = Str::random(14);

        $destinationPath    = 'public/uploads/' . $id;
        $filename           = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $mime_type          = $file->getMimeType();
        $extension          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $upload_success     = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Only videos are allowed to be uploaded.');
    }
}

return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'The videos have been uploaded.');
});
```

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks as though you are storing `Input::file('videos')` to `$files` but you are validating `$file`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Hence $files as $file @user3158900

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to use `size` in spite of `max` in the validation rules, and `flv,mp4,wmv, and so on`. What kind of error do you get? Validation errors?